# How to calculate the average of times stored as strings?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, average

My table contains times stored as strings:

```
select s.average from Tabela s;

AVERAGE
--------
1:26:27
0:10:03
0:10:04
0:10:15
0:09:40
0:09:32
0:09:55
```

I need to get the average of those times. I tried to use:

```
select avg(to_char(to_timestamp(s.average,'hh24:mi:ss'))) from Tabela s
```

But I can't use `avg()` like that; it gets "ORA-01722: invalid number".

How can I calculate the average of these time values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting the string to a timestamp, then back to a string, then trying to average that. You can't average a timestamp value anyway though.

You can convert each string to a time on a nominal date, and get the offset from a fixed date (e.g. the epoch date for convenience), which will be a number of days including fractional parts:

```
select average,
  to_date(average, 'HH24:MI:SS') as dt,
  to_date(average, 'HH24:MI:SS') - date '1970-01-01' as dt_diff
from tabela;

AVERAGE DT                        DT_DIFF
------- ------------------- -------------
1:26:27 2016-04-01 01:26:27   16892.06003
0:10:03 2016-04-01 00:10:03   16892.00698
0:10:04 2016-04-01 00:10:04   16892.00699
0:10:15 2016-04-01 00:10:15   16892.00712
0:09:40 2016-04-01 00:09:40   16892.00671
0:09:32 2016-04-01 00:09:32   16892.00662
0:09:55 2016-04-01 00:09:55   16892.00689
```

You can then average that number-of-days difference, and add it back to the same fixed date, and finally extract the time portion as a string:

```
select avg(to_date(average, 'HH24:MI:SS') - date '1970-01-01') as avg_dt_diff,
  to_char(date '1970-01-01' + avg(to_date(average, 'HH24:MI:SS') - date '1970-01-01'),
    'HH24:MI:SS') as result
from tabela;

  AVG_DT_DIFF RESULT 
------------- --------
  16892.01448 00:20:51
```

This will only work if the string all represent less than 24 hours; the `to_date()` will fail if you exceed that.

---

You can also do it with intervals but they're a bit more of a pain to work with:

```
select average, to_dsinterval('0 ' || average) as avg_int
from tabela;

AVERAGE AVG_INT   
------- -----------
1:26:27 0 1:26:27.0
0:10:03 0 0:10:3.0 
0:10:04 0 0:10:4.0 
0:10:15 0 0:10:15.0
0:09:40 0 0:9:40.0 
0:09:32 0 0:9:32.0 
0:09:55 0 0:9:55.0
```

And then extract the number of seconds and convert to another interval:

```
select numtodsinterval(avg((extract(hour from avg_int) * 60 * 60)
    + (extract(minute from avg_int) * 60)
    + extract(second from avg_int)), 'SECOND') as result
from (
  select to_dsinterval('0 ' || average) as avg_int
  from tabela
);

RESULT    
-------------------
0 0:20:50.857142857
```

Which is more accurate, but you'd have to extract the elements again to get as a string.